# Open/Closed principle and enterprise WCF services

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, open-closed-principle

I'm in the process of Developing and Maintaining a set of WCF services. The functionality is grouped in the services. Payment stuff goes in one service, pure Data in another, and application functions (mostly CRUD) in the third.

About every release cycle, another team requests something from our closed database so we add a method on the data service.

We're trying to move away from the terrible coding of our predecessors(they used hungarian notation and nested try/catches instead of loops) and towards things like object oriented programming.

Can the Open/Closed principle apply to services written in WCF without writing new services each time? Is it worth the time to try?

Thanks.

Comment: I am gonna try to understand what you really want. So you want to deliver new piece of requirement using OOPs and WCF pattern, while leave the current functionality running as it is. and then slowly move stuff feature by feature to new patterns/models. Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Interesting question. But unless you're interested in general advice, perhaps you could show your service contract (or a representative subset) so that we can see what kind of duplication or other issues it might have?

Comment: I apologize to the 15 of you that looked at my question, however I've realized by talking with co-workers that there's not much I can do to change our setup, even if I wanted to.